# WPF Databinding TabItem Headers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am binding a ObservableCollection of data objects to my tab control item source. I have correctly figured out how to bind the controls within the tabitem that is generated, however I cannot figure out how to change the header property of the tabitem that is generated using the a property within the Observable Collection. Sorry if I am wording this incorrectly. Here is my XAML for the tabitem data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
        <TreeView Height="461" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="625" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeviewDataSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a `Style` for your TabItems that sets the `Header` property, and apply the style to `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle`

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding PathToYourProperty}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 15):

Set the DisplayMemberPath on the TabControl to the name of the property.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="headerPropertyName">
```

Comment: I had to use this with Caliburn and convention binding: `<TabControl x:Name="SectionViewModels" DisplayMemberPath="HeaderText" />`